# how to convert a j2me application into android application?

Tags: android, java-me, apk

I am working in a j2me application .and its almost over now i want to convert it in to android (.apk). i just want know that is there any tool available for doing all those conversion stuffs.

Comment: you can not convert j2me application t android , both are totally different sdk
as you need to create new one

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://www.assembla.com/wiki/show/j2ab/Converting_From_J2ME

Comment: its about making new project not converting existing